# which data structure should i choose and why

Tags: c, data-structures

Im writing timers manager in C, which involves:

- creating new timer
- removing timers
- removing dead timer
- freezing timers
- and all the other stuff which i did not yet think about.

The key is - amount of memory should be as small as possible.
At first i thought about linked list, but if i remove some of the middle part, i should rebuild list, which can take some time. Typical dynamic array is the same - i should be carefull with pointers to not miss some of them, when Im rebuliding that structure.

Any ideas ?

Thx for all answer

Comment: Well ususally it is one of the strength of (doubly) linked list to modify it in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to rebuild anything when removing from a linked list. It's an `O(1)` op. No matter what structure you'll choose you'll probably have to be careful about pointers.

Comment: This is misleading - it's only an O(1) op if you're removing from either end, or you already have a reference to the item. If you have to find an item in the list to remove it, it is not O(1). From the question, it seems that removing timers could happen anywhere in the list.

Comment: @PFHayes I assumed a doubly-linked list. If you don't know how to remove an element from a doubly-linked list in constant time, ask a question - I'll help you :-). Phrase it like this: "*I don't know how to remove an element in constant time from a list*".

Comment: What I mean is that it is not clear from the question if the list is being used to lookup timers, or just maintain the list. If you are iterating through the list, and removing all dead timers, then removing each one is O(1). If you are trying to remove an arbitrary timer from the list, then it has to be found first, which is linear.

Comment: @PFHayes You can keep a link to the list node with your timer. I mean, keep a `struct node *link` inside the timer structure. Then you'll skip de searching part.

Comment: @PFHayes: if this is a timer API, then presumably when a user creates a timer it gives the user some kind of handle that can be used to cancel the timer. If this handle is a pointer to the list node, there's no need for a linear search to remove it. So while you're right that sometimes removal will require a search first, it's not the case that removing an arbitrary timer always requires a linear search - you'd only search if you're removing a timer according to some match with a property stored in the node.

Comment: This is assuming of course that you're happy to hand out pointers as your handles - there are situations where you wouldn't, such as RPC.

Comment: I agree. Consider editing this information into the original answer to help the asker of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally an array uses minimal memory. Single block, so less allocation overhead, and no management overhead like the next/previous pointers in a linked list.

Of course it's less time-efficient to remove from the start/middle of a sufficiently large array than it is to remove a given node from a linked list, and also any pointers/indexes into the array will no longer refer to the same element once you've done that, so you have to be careful what handles you give to users of the timer API and how you find the timer data for a particular handle. But if memory use really is the only important issue then the array wins.

I've done something like this before and personally I'd start with a linked list, unless it was obviously going to fail some particular constraint. An array of pointers to "timerdata" structs might also work well, provided you can prevent the list of active timers getting too big.

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of memory has to be as small as possible I would go for an array, the only downside to using an array is that resizing the array is expensive (lots of cpu cycles), However if you can set an upper limit on the number of timers then using a single array sized to this max value will be efficient. If the number of timers is extremely dynamic a list (vector collection) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a heap/priority queue. This has the same memory requirements as an array but insertion and removal are O(lg n) ops. The items in the queue could be ordered by the time-left-to-trigger of each timer object. When a real timer triggers you'll have to adjust the trigger time of every other timer in the list. So, if timer1 is set to go off after 1 second, and timer2 is set to go off after 1.5 seconds, when timer1 triggers you'll have to adjust timer2 to go off after 0.5 seconds. Something like that maybe?

Answer (score 0):

What is a timer element? What's in it?  Is it just a value that is continually counted down by some timer interrupt or some complex class, perhaps with its own thread that does timing?

What operations are likely to be performed most often? - optimize access to those as a priority.

Is there any advantage to be had in ordering the list, eg. in ascending expiry-time order, so that the timer timing out next is always at the start of the list, (ie. delta-queue).

Rgds,
Martin